# Bentching after vomiting

Tags: blessing, bentching, choleh-sick

If someone gets sick during a meal, assuming they are not incapacitated as a result, should they still Bentch, or do we say that they did not gain any nourishment and it's like they didn't eat (or at least like they didn't eat enough to constitute a meal)?

Comment: 101% chance the Minchat Chinuch has 17 cases which are variations of this.

Comment: @DoubleAA See Minchas Chinuch ([313](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14092&st=&pgnum=156&hilite=)).

Comment: @Fred Good find! (I added a link into your comment)

Answer (score 8):

See *Har Tz'vi* (OC 1:163) where he discusses this issue. He first quotes the *Panim M'iros* (2:27), *Chasam Sofer* (OC 127), and the *Minchas Chinuch* (313), who hold that *hana'as mei'av* is a necessary criterion for *birkas hamazon*. Therefore, these opinions hold, if someone ate half of a *k'zayis*, then vomited it up, then ate another half *k'zayis*, he would be exempt from *birkas hamazon* (see also *Chullin* 103b). The *Har Tz'vi* infers from these opinions that if someone ate a *k'zayis* at one time, there might be grounds to say that *birkas hamazon* is required.

However, he then quotes the Gra (*Kol Eliyahu*, § 9), who writes that if someone vomited out all of what he ate, he is exempt from *birkas hamazon* because this is similar to a case of delaying *bentching* until after the food is digested (whereupon one can no longer *bentch*).

The responsum concludes by referencing the *Imrei Binah* (OC, § 14), who writes that even if a person kept a little bit of the *k'zayis* down, he should not *bentch* because *kdei sviah* does not remain in his digestive tract.

See also *Torah Lishmah* (§ 125), who writes that someone who vomits, if he won't be able to eat more and keep it down, should bentch without *shem u'malchus*.

Comment: What does he mean in regards to being full for kiddush? When is anybody ever full during kiddush, a person only eats after kiddush?

Comment: @user6591 He's probably talking about a case where someone was eating a meal on Erev Shabbos and continued it into kiddush. Some kind of *poreis mappa um'kadeish* situation (*P'sachim* 100a).

Comment: Ah. Makes sense. Ty